# Tailwind CSS color not displayed in tsx

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, colors, tailwind-css, tsx

normal:
[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNDjy.png)

But my color doesn't show.
[abnormal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gI2YE.png)

I am trying to install TailWind Css IntelliSense. Although it can provide some functions, it does not have the color blocks I want.

I am running in the next.js 13 environment, and this is my configuration:

```
/* tailwind.config.js */

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {}
  },
  plugins: []
}
```

```
/* postcss.config.js */

module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you miss out this code in `globals.css`

Add this code in `globals.css`

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: no, maybe vscode itself is the problem, I recently updated vscode and found that everything is fine